# How to get time from string H:M:S in C

Tags: c, string, time

I need to extract hours, minutes and seconds from a string formatted as e.g: "00:53:12" to variables a, b and c.

How would I go about this in C?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [strptime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/strptime.html)

```
struct tm tm;

if (strptime("00:53:12", "%H:%M:%S", &tm) != NULL)
   printf("hour: %d; minutes: %d; seconds: %d;\n",
      tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use standard function [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime):

strptime(timestr,"%H:%M:%S", ret)